# Why is running f[1]() different in Version B than in Version A, below?

Tags: javascript, html

Why is running f1 different in Version B than in Version A, below?
// Version A

```
var f = {};
for( var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++ ) {
f[i] = function() { alert(i); }
}
```

// Version B

```
var f = {};
for( var i=0 ; i<3 ; i++ ) {
f[i] = function(j) { return function() { alert(j); }; }(i);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 4):

The first code snippet makes 3 functions that are bound to `i`.

The second code snippet makes 3 functions that are *closed* around the value of `i` - a **closure**.

This means that in the first example, if you do:

```
i = "hi";
f[0](); // "hi"
```

Minor:

`f` should probably be initialized as `f = []` since you're using it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of a concept called as a **closure** where the values of the parameters of the function returning the function are preserved in the returned function